# Changepoint detection in a single unevenly spaced time series

Tags: time-series, change-point, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a single time series, unevenly spaced. I would like to perform change point detection on it. Does it mean a non-parametric method is needed? Any pointers to which method would be valid? Also, it has only 70 data points. The 'change point' package in R implements PELT, SegNeigh & BinSeg, any opinions?

Comment: What are you looking for changes in?  If it is the trend then unevenly spaced data matters more than for changes in a flat mean.